# Default browser for specific solution in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I want to debug my silverlight project in IE and debug other ASP.Net <del>projects</del> websites on firefox.

How to set default browser for specific solution?

EDITED: it is website, not project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best option here, would be to use command line arguments when starting debugging.

You can do that on a project-by-project setting.

Just chose 'Start Options', Command Line, then add either iexplore.exe or firefox.exe with the path to your default page.

That should sort you out.

Comment: Or right-click on the page and choose Browse-with - then choose your browser...   up to you.

Comment: right-click & choose browse with actually is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: yes, it works. but I can't debug my silverlight project. It never hit any breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the project debug options to not display a web page and then open whatever browser you prefer.

Comment: I'm sorry. it is an ASP.Net website (not web project) on my Silverlight project.